# Работа скрипта PHP по принципу транзакций

Tags: php

Я вообще сам по себе Педант и не люблю когда в той или иной директории или БД остается мусор по средствам сбоев или ошибок программы.
Я никогда не писал серьезных проектов и дабы получить урок путем прочтения ваших комментов, я задам ряд вопрос детально все расписав.

К примеру, имеется скрипт, который позволяет двум пользователь общаться между собой, обмениваться фотографиями, видео, музыкой и т.д., а принцип скрипта следующий:

Пользователь печатает сообщение, загружает фото (файлы грузятся во временную папку по ajax) и музыкальный файл, затем кликает кнопку "Отправить" и данные улетают на сервер, а на сервере происходит следующее:

Текстовое сообщение записывается в БД, затем следующий шаг это запись в другую таблицу инфо о фотографии (путь к фото, размеры и т.д.), а потом перемещение фотографии из временной директории в постоянную, то же самое и с музыкальным файлом.
Казалось бы всё прекрасно, мы получили ожидаемый результат, но а что если после того как текстовое сообщение запишется в БД и информация о файле тоже будет записана, то после произойдет сбой?! Ведь сбои могут быть? Это ведь техника. С сервером, интернетом и т.д. всё что угодно может произойти в процессе выполнения.

На выходе мы получаем сообщение, которое без вложений да и более того, половину информации о вложениях записалось, а половина нет и ещё непонятно где сами файлы остались.

Ко мне в голову пришла идея вначале выполнения кода реализоваться что-то типа карты, к примеру, из массива и в неё записать всю информацию, а именно:
- Полный путь к файлам из временной папки
- Полный путь к файлам куда мы должны будем переместить файлы из временно папки
- И прочую возможную информацию информацию

И эту карту сразу же первым делом записать в таблицу (не буду описывать куда, главное понять, что эта инфа записана)

И по завершению скрипта, если всё прошло успешно, то удаляем карту, а если карта, к примеру, после обновления страницы осталась в таблице, значит скрипт сработал некорректно и просто по этой карте пробегаем и все отовсюду удаляем.

Я не пытаюсь что-то изобрести или открыть, я просто хотел бы знать, нужно ли подобное реализовывать? Или есть более простой способ о котором я никогда не слышал? Или, может быть, всё это дикий бред?
С радостью выслушаю вас и получу дельные советы.
Спасибо!!!

Comment: Вы можете всю информацию сразу сохранить в посте. только пишите его сразу целиком во все таблицы в одной транзакции. И в посте статус операций. мне что то подсказывает, что достаточно просто "все завершено/в работе". Хотя конечно можете стадии фиксировать. Очень желательно что бы временная и рабочая папки были на одной файловой системе. Что бы файлы именно перенести move, а не читать-писать. move правит только записи каталогов.

Comment: Но 100% гарантии никто не даст. Это БД следит за тем, что бы данные физически попали на диск. А файловая система кеширует запись и после неожиданной перезагрузки может выяснится, что файлы не перенеслись или стали нулевой длины (xfs часто так прикалывается). Конечно можно давать sync, но частые синки будут тормозить. Так что я бы сделал процедуру чистки мусора. А пост пока он завершенным не помечен не показывать всем, а только создавшему, что бы после сбоя он мог догрузить файлы, поправить что то

Comment: Фиксация стадий подразумевает под собой частые запросы к БД. У меня под вечер уже голова не соображает. Загляну я сюда завтра))) Нагруженный день сегодня был.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
если данные не провалидировались - эксепшен
begin в бд, 
    делаем записи в таблицы, 
    произошла ошибка, rollback, эксепшен // баг в валидации
    //или сломалась бд, кончилось место, неправильный запрос
    //если все окей с созданием записи в бд:
    записываем файл, 
    если файл не записался/был испорчен: удаляем файл, rollback, эксепшен
иначе - commit
```

можете, например, если не очень высокая нагрузка, хранить файлы в бд, тогда откат будет и файлы откатывать.

или, допустим, вы можете сделать скрипт, который будет бегать по базе данных и списку файлов каждый день и проверять валидность файлов, плохие - удалять.

тема очень большая, на самом деле и вопрос очень широкий,  и для маленьких проектов без супервысокой нагрузки обычное решение в таких случаях просто восстановление из частого бэкапа в случае каких-то ошибок.

в больших проектах - все сложнее и в одном посте не напишешь.

остальной функционал (типа после коммитов файл испортился  и т.д.) решается уже по сути кластерными методами - три сервера, если на одном файл испортился, диск поехал и т.д., то правильной считается версия, совпадающая на двух других серверах. в космических аппартах и мэйнфреймах существует примерно такое же дублирование на уровне компьютеров/процессоров

почитайте про архитектуры netflix и google - они такие проблемы как раз решают часто. (netflix c ошибками на машинах борется [забавным](https://github.com/Netflix/SimianArmy) образом - они рэндомно убивают хосты в сети, каждый день, для того, чтобы процесс восстановления был идеально отлажен)

p.s. вопрос "нужно ли подобное реализовывать" - очень зависит от вашего сервиса и предполагаемого уровня его качества. одно дело - пользователи обмениваются сообщениями в соцсети и один раз из миллиона происходит ошибка выкладки фотографии, пользователь просто перезагрузит ее еще раз, а если допустим, у вас сервис управления сетью ПВО и какая-то из пусковых установок получила сломанный файл с картой местности - oche ploho, на учениях вам в офис может прилететь ракета.

Comment: У меня движок MyISAM и он не поддерживает транзакции на уровне БД, к сожалению. В любом случае, мне есть что почитать, спасибо!

Comment: без использования транзакционной бд нет особого смысла работать  делать транзакционные программы (можно, но будет медленней, больше лишнего кода и больше ошибок)